# Floated div must scroll horizontally, outer div vertical scroll should work for both div

Tags: html, css, scroll

I want a table kind of structure. First column is Question and Second Column is comments which is row spanned.

For this I used floated div

Both should scroll vertically by the parent. But Second column alone should contain horizontal scroll

I am able to get the output, but the scroll is appearing only at the bottom of the page.

But I want horizontal scroll which should be fixed at the bottom of parent div, if I make this as output I am not able to scroll the second column along with its parent.

Horizontal Scroll is working fine. Need to solve vertical scroll

How to overcome with this problem?

```css
#outer{
    height : 50px;
    overflow-x : hidden;
    overflow-y : scroll;
    border : 1px solid black;
}
#inner1{
    float : left;
    width : 20%;
    height : 100%;
}
#inner2{
    width : 80%;
    height : 100%;
    overflow-y : hidden;
}

.innerSub2{
    width : 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner1">
        <div class="innerSub1">Question</div>
        <div class="innerSub1">Question</div>
        <div class="innerSub1">Question</div>
        <div class="innerSub1">Question</div>
    </div>
    <div id = "inner2">
        <div class="innerSub2">Comment</div>
        <div class="innerSub2">Comment</div>
        <div class="innerSub2">Comment</div>
        <div class="innerSub2">Comment</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe inner2 div on top of the outer div, i don't know anything better.

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
.topicwrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow : hidden;
    border : 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.outer{
    position: relative;
    height : 50px;    
    overflow-x : hidden;
    overflow-y : scroll;
    z-index: 0;
}
.inner1{
    float : left;
    width : 20%;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
.inner2{
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 0px;   
    width : 80%;
    height: 50px;
    overflow-y : hidden;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    z-index: 99;
}
.innerSub1{
    width: 20%;
}
.innerSub2{
    width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topicwrap">
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner1">
        <div class="innerSub1">Question1</div>
        <div class="innerSub1">Question2</div>
        <div class="innerSub1">Question3</div>
        <div class="innerSub1">Question4</div>
        <div class="innerSub1">Question5</div>
        <div class="innerSub1">Question6</div>
    </div><!-- end inner1 -->
</div><!-- end outer -->
    <div class="inner2">
        <div class="innerSub2">Comment1</div>
        <div class="innerSub2">Comment2</div>
        <div class="innerSub2">Comment3</div>
        <div class="innerSub2">Comment4</div>
    </div><!-- end inner2 -->
</div><!-- end topic-wrap -->
```

Comment: What I need is my horizontal scroll should be visible always  at the bottom of parent div.  In your code snippet I can see it only when I scroll to bottom of div.

Comment: Thanks, But I was not able to scroll inner2 vertically along with its parent vertical scroll

Comment: Yes that's a problem, than you're looking at scripting that 2 scrollbars scroll at the same time for example, but that's way beyond me. I'm not a expert at all so i hope someone else can have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the scroll for parent div as follows

```css
#outer{
    height : 50px;
    overflow-x : scroll;
    overflow-y : scroll;
    border : 1px solid black;
}
#inner1{
    float : left;
    width : 20%;
    height : 100%;
}
#inner2{
        float : right;
    width : 80%;
    height : 100%;
   // overflow-y : hidden;
}

.innerSub2{
    width : 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner1">
        <div class="innerSub1">Question</div>
        <div class="innerSub1">Question</div>
        <div class="innerSub1">Question</div>
        <div class="innerSub1">Question</div>
    </div>
    <div id = "inner2">
        <div class="innerSub2">Comment</div>
        <div class="innerSub2">Comment</div>
        <div class="innerSub2">Comment</div>
        <div class="innerSub2">Comment</div>
    </div>
</div>
```